# variable still not defined even after adding external JS in VUE component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to import function `marked` from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js`. I have injected `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>` by `mount()`. But it always throws an error `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: marked is not defined"`. Why it is not defined even after the script has been added?

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Upload',
  data () {
    return {
      title: '',
      content: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    let externalScript = document.createElement('script')
    externalScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js')
    Plugin.async = true
    document.head.appendChild(externalScript)
  },
  computed: {
    markdown2html: function () {
      return marked(this.content)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: when app mounted, means all views are rendered. Insert it at head or import it at main.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I'm not familiar with Vue, I use React, but normally I would be able to add the script link in the `index.html` under public folder. Then when everything's built it will be there.

Best option I think would be to install it via `npm` - `npm i marked`, then `import marked from 'marked'` - why not do it this way?